# Create text file using echo in command prompt

Tags: command-line, command, echo, command-prompt

I'm creating a hello_world.txt in the desktop using echo in command prompt and this is my input.

`echo hello world > C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello_world.txt`

The first code works, then I try %userprofile% if example, I want to give it to another user.

`echo hello world > C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\hello_world.txt`

Doesn't work. Any simple echo command line to create text file?

Comment: What is your `command line`? Cygwin under Windows? cmd.exe?

Comment: If you're used to linux shells, you can install `git bash`. You'll have fast all the linux command, and lines like `echo hello world > C:\Users\user\Desktop\hello_world.txt` will normaly work ;)

Comment: can you try to print the viariable `%userprofile%` by doing ech %userprofile% in your commande line

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your command should be:

`echo hello world > %userprofile%\Desktop\hello_world.txt`

---

It doesn't work if you put anything before `%userprofile%`, because it's a full path, so `C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\hello_world.txt` gets substituted to `C:\Users\C:\Users\cromix\Desktop\hello_world.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

**1. To create a new file and new text or To override everything that you have in your file with new text:**

```
echo > file_name text_you_want_to_in_your_file
```

**2. To add next text from new line:**

```
echo >> file_name text_you_want_to_add_in_your_file
```

Answer (score -2):

*You can type*:

`touch <file name>`

*Very important **NOTE***: You can use this command only on **cmder** or Mac OS.

and this works in **Windows** by downloading [cmder](http://cmder.net) **only**.

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twk6E.png)